# Find the number of days in a given month in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I am trying to calculate wages data. Is there a way to calculate the number of days in a given month in sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the year and the month as a number, you can do it with `strftime()`:

```
SELECT strftime('%d', '2021' || '-' || printf('%02d', ?) || '-01', '1 month', '-1 day') days
```

Replace `'2021'` with the year that you want and `?` with the month number.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7b917412b50bd505c953303322fa491e).

Comment: Thanks, I did it using this piece of code at the end, can you please explain the difference between these two ways so I can better understand it

Comment: '1 month', '-1 day' -- your code
'start of month','+1 month','-1 day' -- my code

how exactly does the strftime calculate the difference

Comment: @Rameez strftime() is used to format a date: `'2021' || '-' || printf('%02d', ?) || '-01'` returns the 1st day of a month. Then I add 1 month with `'1 month'` to get the 1st day of the next month and then I subtract 1 day to get the last day of the month that I want. From this date with `strftime(`%d`)` I get only the day part.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do it, but you can use `JULIANDAY` to calculate the difference in days between the date in a month and the current date, which should give you the number of days of the current month.

For example to calculate the number of days in the month that contains the date 2010-05-31;

```
SELECT JULIANDAY('2010-05-31', '+1 month') - JULIANDAY('2010-05-31') days_of_month
> 31
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9eecb7/8296)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DATE` function to get from some date to its month's last day, e.g. from '2021-06-05' to '2021-06-30'. Then use `STRFTIME` to extract that day ('30' in the example). Then cast to `INTEGER` to get from the day string to a number ('30' -> 30).

```
SELECT 
  CAST(
    STRFTIME(
      '%d', 
      DATE(
        '2021-06-05',
        'start of month',
        '+1 month',
        '-1 day'
      )
    ) AS INTEGER
  );
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=45d8620632c831d554b435b501f98912